# Object reference not set to an instance of object in VB

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, registration

I try to register an account but all it says is Object reference not set to an instance of object at the `dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Username").NewRow()` part.

Here's the code listing.

```
    ElseIf inc <> -1 Then

        If Not ExistAccount(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text) Then

            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

            Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

            dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Username").NewRow()

            dsNewRow.Item(1) = txtUsername.Text
            dsNewRow.Item(2) = txtPassword.Text

            ds.Tables("Username").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

            da.Update(ds, "Username")
            txtUsername.Clear()
            txtPassword.Clear()

            MsgBox("Your account has been created.")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ds is Nothing or ds doesn't contains a table named UserName.... show the code that initialize and fill the dataset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error chances are the `ds.Tables("Username")` doesnt exist therefore calling a new row on a null `DataTable` will result in an exception. Check to ensure that the `DataTabe` "Username" is not null before calling the `NewRow()` method.

Something like (this is just an idea)

```
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

If ds.Tables("Username") Is Nothing Then
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Username", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Password", GetType(String))

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

End If

dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Username").NewRow()
```

Now the whole section about creating a new table is optional and up to you if that's the direction you would like to go with if the table does not exist. Again the main point is changes are the "Username" table does not exist.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since DataRow type is an object, you might try

```
     SET  dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Username").NewRow()
```

Comment: Set isn't needed in VB.NET

Comment: The TAGS on this item were set to 
         "database vb.net ms-access registration"
and I had filtered on ms-access but I did not notice the vb.net

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the New keyword to instanciate the Datarow as:

```
Dim dsNewRow As New DataRow
```

Comment: The answer is incorrect

Comment: AND he has that in the code

Comment: There is no constructor for a DataRow accessible by user code. Even if that was possible, what kind of schema such a constructor would build for that row?